# high speed regular expression using multicharacter NFA for java

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a high speed regular expression matching engine for java .
Is the Java regex framework known to be the faster?

Also i [Learnt](http://cial.csie.ncku.edu.tw/st2008/pdf/HIGH-SPEED%20REGULAR%20EXPRESSION%20MATCHING%20ENGINE%20USING%20MULTI-CHARACTER%20NFA.pdf) that , "High-speed regular expression matching engine using multicharacter NFA" is faster , is there a java implementation for the same ?
Edit : this [link](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html), shows a NFA based approach that is faster
Or are there any other faster regular expression matching engines in java ?

Comment: Not sure about the detail implementation, but the implementation is usually highly performant.

Comment: Most users find it fast enough, assuming the regexes themselves are well written.  Have you tried it?  What are you using it for?

Comment: I am trying to fix performance problems in an eventing system, that processes high number of events , we check for a pattern first to see if we need to process the event or not, my hunch is we can improve this step. ofcourse along with other parts of the system

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this [article](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/tomwhite/archive/2006/03/a_faster_java_r.html) to read about *dk.brics.automaton* library. According to the benchmark linked in the article, it is approximately x20 faster than the JDK implementation.

The linked library was written by Anders Møller and had also been [mavenized](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dk.brics.automaton/automaton/1.11-8).